# how to run simple ejb program?

Tags: java, ejb

I use myeclipse and jboss5.0.1 server.mysql is the database that i use.

I want to run simple ejb program on myeclipse.

Comment: You don't "run" an EJB, and there is no such thing as "an EJB program". Perhaps you want to run the server from within the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the program is a jar file containing EJB's, the basic steps to go through for running an EJB Project through eclipse are:

- Import / create the project in your workspace as an "EJB Project" i.e. File > New > EJB Project. This will add the facets to allow you to deploy on your server.
- Register the JBoss application server with eclipse. Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Add
- Right click the EJB Project and select Run As > Run On Server and select Manually define a new server. Then select JBoss.

You should then be able to start and stop the server through myeclipse.